# Como somar o resto da divisão com o último Value de um dicionário?

Tags: c#, lista, dicionário

Eu tenho o total de uma lista de compra e preciso dividir este total pela quantidade de `emails` que possuo na minha segunda lista e retornar um dicionário. Porém, nem toda a divisão é exata, então preciso somar o resto de divisões não exatas ao último `Value` do dicionário.

Existe algum método pra pegar o último valor e fazer a alteração?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace listas {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        List<Itens> itens = new List<Itens>();
        itens.Add(new Itens() {
            Item = "Pendrive", Quantidade = 2, ValorUND = 20
        });
        itens.Add(new Itens() {
            Item = "Fones de ouvido", Quantidade = 2, ValorUND = 20
        });
        itens.Add(new Itens() {
            Item = "SSD 10GB", Quantidade = 1, ValorUND = 20
        });

        List<string> emails = new List<string>();
        emails.Add("marcos@example.com");
        emails.Add("pedro@example.com");
        emails.Add("joao@example.com");

        Calcula(itens, emails);
    }

    static Dictionary<string,int> Calcula(List<Itens> lista1, List<string> lista2) 
    {
        int total = 0;
        int resto;
        Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < lista1.Count; i++) {
            total += (lista1[i].Quantidade * lista1[i].ValorUND);
        }

        total = total / lista2.Count;
        resto = total % lista2.Count;

        lista2.ForEach((string email) => {
            dict.Add(email, total);
        });

        if (resto != 0) {

        }

        foreach(KeyValuePair < string, int > d in dict) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{d.Key}: {d.Value.ToString("
          C ")}");
        }

        return dict;

    }
  }
}
```

> [image: Neste caso, eu teria que somar o resto(1) + 33 no último valor pra soma ser 100 igual ao total]

Comment: Não tem como saber o último valor de um dicionário, é uma coleção desordenada. Fonte: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2 "For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue> structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined."

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, não entendo muito bem do Dictionary, mas já tentou criar uma variavel para saber qual é o ultimo valor e depois apenas chamar ele? Tipo assim:

```
int x = dict.count; 

// depois chamar, caso queira exibir
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(lista[x].ValorUND));
```

Não sei se é exatamente assim a linhagem do código, mas foi a logica que tive.

Answer (score 0):

Como não tinha como saber o último valor do dicionário, eu criei uma nova lista para armazenar os values do dicionário, de acordo com o tamanho da lista que é recebida como argumento da função:

```
List<int> valores = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < lista2.Count; i++)
        {
            valores.Add(total);
        }
```

Em seguida, fiz um Do While para distribuir o resto da divisão entre os elementos da lista:

```
int n = 0;
        do
        {
            valores[n] = valores[n] + 1;
            n++;
        } while (n < resto);
```

Ao final, fiz um loop pra adicionar ao dicionário os elementos da lista2 como keys, e os elementos da lista valores como values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lista2.Count; i++)
        {
            dict.Add(lista2[i], valores[i]);
        }
```